# Access Denied when I tried setting my own VENV in python, what do I do?

Tags: python

I have a legit issue I wrote below into cmd

```
C:>python39>python.exe -m venv %USERPROFILE%\venvs\demoenv3    https:// past ebin . c om/2QDHwz0z
```

I was writing along with a tutorial video I grabbed from Idemy. I wrote this code as trying to write my own Venv and now I get nothing but access denied anytime I type in python, Python, and that same Venv is now access denied in CMD < not Python terminal (overall Cmd).

No clue what to do now Python access denied

> C:\Users\Asus>3+3 '3+3' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command,   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\Asus>python  Access is denied.
>
> C:\Users\Asus>

I tried doing math to see if Python was active, which was able to add up 3 plus 3

Comment: Below instructions do nothing still not accessible

Answer (score 0):

Go to the python folder
Right click on it
Select Properties
Click on the tab Security
Select Advance
Click on the Add
Click on select principal
Click on advance
Click on find now
In the list given select your  user name Ausus
Click on ok
Click on ok
Select all check boxes
Click on ok
Click on apply

Comment: Yea I did that and didn't work. Still locked out. Thanks for attempting though